# Problema com versão do JAVAC para compilação dinâmica

Tags: java, compilação

Eu estou tentando compilar uma classe HelloWorld para teste, e está dando um erro do qual não sei como solucionar. Alguém sabe uma solução? Pelo que parece, é algum problema relacionado a versão.

Estou tentando compilar assim:

```
String arquivo2 = "/C:/classes/HelloWorld.java";
        PrintWriter saida = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("logCompilacao.txt"));

        int resultadoCompilacao = com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(new String[]{arquivo2},saida);
```

Mas o resultado é esse:

```
/C:/classes/HelloWorld.java:2: cannot access java.lang.Object
bad class file: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/Object.class)
class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 49.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
public class HelloWorld {
       ^
1 error
```

***-----------class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 49.0---------***

Como solucionar? Que problema de versão é esse? 
Adicionado: Executei `java -version` e `javac -version` e ambos retornaram 1.8.0_73

Comment: Tentando compilar usando versão de Java diferente. Só pera aí, major version 49? Isso é Java 5, quem ainda usa isso o_0

Comment: Mas meu java tá na versão mais recente. Seria isso um problema no jar do javac?

Comment: Não não, o seu Java é 52(Java 8), o fonte que foi construído com Java 5. Vê bem se a primeira pasta Java que aparece no seu %PATH% e o JAVA_HOME(se tiver) é Java 8 também.

Comment: @DH. o que quer dizer com "primeira pasta java do meu "%PATH%?" Se está se referindo a variável de ambiente Path, ela está assim: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;;%JAVA_HOME%\bin e a minha JAVA_HOME está assim: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73

Comment: @AraújoFilho só uma dica, ficar editando constantemente sem acrescentar em nada na pergunta não ajuda muito. Aguarde até alguém possa te ajudar, ficar editando costantemente faz com que pareça que você está editando propositalmente para que ela ganhe destaque.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado @DiegoF

Comment: Rode os comandos `java -version` e `javac -version` e adicione na pergunta, o problema pode ser versoes diferentes entre o jdk e a jre.

Comment: Pronto, fiz essa nova edição para adicionar o conteúdo a pergunta @DiegoF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente consegui resolver meu problema. Parece que por padrão o eclipse importa apenas jars da jre. Então eu tive que adicionar como uma jar externa o arquivo 'tools.jar' que fica na minha pasta da jdk. `C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\lib\tools.jar`

Depois de fazer isso eu consegui compilar o que eu queria.

Answer (score 0):

É possível que esse exemplo o ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12246348/4219136

Tente adicionar **"-source", "1.5", "-target", "1.5"** como opções de compilação:

```
String[] optionsAndSources = {
            "-source", "1.5",
            "-target", "1.5", 
            arquivo2 
        };

int status =  Main.compile(optionsAndSources, out);
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou para o meu caso. O erro continua o mesmo